# 500 error writing to PDF using Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I have Zend working properly, and it will open a PDF, and save it, but when I try to actually use drawText to write some text over the PDF, I get this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Zend_Pdf::drawText() in /home/whatever/test.php
```

I don't understand why it won't work, thoughts?

Comment: `drawText()` is not a method of `Zend_Pdf` but `Zend_Pdf_Page`. I cannot say more until I see a little bit of code

Comment: You do you call "Zend_Pdf::drawText()"?
Read here: http://devzone.zend.com/1064/zend_pdf-tutorial/

Comment: the writer of the tutorial was documenting how to create a new pdf page (I'm not sure if you can edit a PDF in ZF) and in that context was calling static methods from Zend_Pdf_Page like: `$page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);` so when he calls `$page->drawText()` the context is Zend_Pdf_Page. Also the tutorial was written in 2007, it might be a little out of date...(shrugs) or not.

Comment: You sure /home/whatever/test.php is either an action or controller? from the sound of it, it doesn't seem to be.